# Is there a possibility to scrape an entire job offering database?

Tags: json

I am trying to automatically retrieve all active job listings from Deutsche Telekom from the following website: https://telekom.jobs/global-careers

At the moment, there are 1,813 job offerings.

There seems to be an API that returns JSON code (https://telekom.jobs/globaljobboard_api/v3/search/), however the results are limited to 10 (SearchResultCount).

Is there any possibility to parse some parameters to the API so it returns a JSON file with all 1,800 current job offerings?

Thanks

I have tried to add some parameters to the URL, however I was not succesfull with it

```
https://telekom.jobs/globaljobboard_api/v3/search/%7B%22JobadID%22:%22%22,%22LanguageCode%22:%222%22,%22SearchParameters%22:%7B%22FirstItem%22:1,%22CountItem%22:10000,%22Sort%22:[%7B%22Criterion%22:%22FavoriteJobIndicator%22,%22Direction%22:%22DESC%22%7D],%22MatchedObjectDescriptor%22:[%22ID%22,%22PositionTitle%22,%22ParentOrganization%22,%22ParentOrganizationName%22,%22PositionURI%22,%22PositionLocation.CountryName%22,%22PositionLocation.CountrySubDivisionName%22,%22PositionLocation.CityName%22,%22PositionLocation.Longitude%22,%22PositionLocation.Latitude%22,%22PositionBenefit.Code%22,%22PositionBenefit.Name%22,%22FavoriteJobIndicator%22,%22FavoriteJobIndicatorName%22]%7D,%22SearchCriteria%22:[%7B%22CriterionName%22:%22PositionLocation.Latitude%22,%22CriterionValue%22:[%2250.73743%22]%7D,%7B%22CriterionName%22:%22PositionLocation.Longitude%22,%22CriterionValue%22:[%227.098206800000071%22]%7D,%7B%22CriterionName%22:%22PositionLocation.Distance%22,%22CriterionValue%22:[%229.013064227023515%22]%7D,%7B%22CriterionName%22:%22PositionLocation.CountryCode%22,%22CriterionValue%22:[%22DE%22]%7D,%7B%22CriterionName%22:%22PositionLocation.AreaCode%22,%22CriterionValue%22:[%22DE%22]%7D]
```

My expected results are a JSON file of the whole database, not only the ten most recent entries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do a `POST` with the data `{"SearchParameters":{"CountItem":1813}}`.

Here an example using `curl`:

```
curl 'https://telekom.jobs/globaljobboard_api/v3/search/' -H 'Accept: application/json' --compressed -H 'Content-Type: application/json' --data '{"SearchParameters":{"CountItem":1813}}'
```

Notice this is particular to this API, this will not necessarily work for others.